# Access multiple user inboxes via the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, office365api

How do you use [Microsoft's Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) to access the "Sent Items" folder for all users within an Outlook 365 organization account?

I'm trying to integrate a legacy analytics application with Outlook, and it needs to be able to read (but not send) all email from all users within an organization.

I've used their [quickstart](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) example Python code to get the inbox for the admin user on an Outlook 365 account, but I don't see anyway to do widen this for all users without having each user go through the Oauth verification link. Is this supported by the API?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible though application permissions (often referred to as app only context) as opposed to delegated permissions (user context).

This will require the consent from an administrator for all tenant and won't require consent from each user.

More information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types